# Porque salen botones LEARN MORE y el botón Toggle cookie en una barra roja consent bar al ejecutar la aplicación

Tags: c#, .net-core

Como puedo deshabilitar esa fea barra roja y ese botón que se despliega detras de la página de login al ejecutar el proyecto.

Estoy usabdo visual studio 2017 como IDE.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta implementado así por defecto en el template ese banner debes personalizarlo. Y esta así para cumplir con GPPR.

Si no lo quieres o deseas hacer tu propio banner en la configuración lo deshabilitas, vas a Startup.cs y cambias...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies 
        // is needed for a given request.
        // A Q U I ponlo en false
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```